# Enable HTTPS in an web application

Tags: https

I am working in a web app that uses a frontend (AngularJS) and a backend server (NodeJS, Express) separately.

We want to redirect all urls to "https://www".

So we found a certificate (which works) and enabled SSL in our frontend.
Then I've changed our api call constant to now send requests to https://api.myapp.com/api/... 
instead of 
http://api.myapp.com:PORT/api

I then assume that we would have to enable https on our backend in our nodejs script.

So my questions are:
Do I need another other certificate? How should I enable https on my backend? Do I only need to make the server accepts https requests? Is it a NPM module?

For now, it tells me "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when I'm trying to send a call to https://api.myapp.com/api/ instead of http://api.myapp.com:PORT/api

probably because my nodejs doesn't handle https requests.

Https is a new thing for me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to use HTTPS, you **need** to use **443 port**, that said, your https server **has** to be listening to that port, you'll have to specify in the URL otherwise, the `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` confirms my suspicion.

In express.js >= 3, you need to use the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var pKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcertificate.key', 'utf8');
var cert = fs.readFileSync('sslcertificate.crt', 'utf8');
var creds = {key: pKey  , cert: cert };
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpsServer = https.createServer(creds , app);
// Note the 443 port
httpsServer.listen(443);
```